# Django_hosts Not Working With Django's Default Authentication

Tags: python, django

I'm using this package called [django_hosts](https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts) to re-route urls for some apps.

Everything is working fine except for the fact that django_hosts is not working with Django Authentication.

I hosted this url api.example.com, so on this page with the url api.example.com:8000/add_post, I want users to add post but before doing that you must be authenticated. So after I logged in, I still can't submit post via the form talkless of posting. But when I go back to example.com, it shows that I'm logged in but api.example.com is telling me otherwise.

How do I make django authentication work with this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the authentication token is hooked to the domain. Using Django's default configuration, the `api.example.com` can't access the `example.com` auth token.

You can change this behaviour by setting the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` configuration in your **settings.py** module:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'example.com'
```

**But not too fast! Do it carefully, otherwise you can break your application:**

> Be cautious when updating this setting on a production site. If you
>   update this setting to enable cross-domain cookies on a site that
>   previously used standard domain cookies, existing user cookies will be
>   set to the old domain. This may result in them being unable to log in
>   as long as these cookies persist.

More info on the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN).